# root/misc/build-native.sh not exists in ics-openvpn

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

Im trying to build [ics-openvpn](https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/), the README said :

```
Do cd main;./misc/build-native.(sh|bat) in the root directory of the project.
```

My main problem is the `build-native.sh` is not even exists in the `misc` folder.

Am i missing something silly? Thanks

Comment: Did you find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. THere is misc/ and main/misc/

Please note that ics-openvpn is under GPLv2.

Comment: Please kindly help me out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010234/ics-openvpn-successfully-running-but-get-syntax-error-in-cache Thanks